# Segfault in native code with jni CALL

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface, thread-safety, native

I m having a segfault in my native C code.

I have a thread pool that contain 4thread in my program, each one do a new MyObject()
in MyObject i have

```
   public class MyObject{

        private final float[] pmt = new float[50];
private final float[] cond = new float[10];
private final float[][] don = new float[3][200000];
private final float[][] abaque = new float[2][100];
private final double[][] res = new double[3][200000];

    private native int trade_OM(float[] pmt, float[][] abaque, float[][] don, float[] cond, double[][] res, int[] flag);

     protected void callNative() {
       trade_OM(pmt, abaque, don, cond, res, flag);
     }

     static {
  System.loadLibrary("myDLL");
     }
    }
```

and when one thread is free, if another task arrived, the thread do a new MyObject() another time and call the native method.

after 6 or 7 call of new MyObject() i have a segfault.

**on solaris i use truss **:

```
 /16:    lwp_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, 0xFFBFFEFF, 0x0000FFF7) = 0xFFBFFEFF [0x0000FFFF]
 /15:    time()                                          = 1398686601
 /17:    llseek(11, 0, SEEK_CUR)                         = 5887547
 /15:    open("Trade.log", O_RDWR|O_APPEND|O_CREAT, 0666) = 8
 /17:    llseek(11, 0, SEEK_CUR)                         = 5887547
 /15:    fstat64(8, 0xACFFD5B0)                          = 0
 /17:    close(11)                                       = 0
 /15:    fstat64(8, 0xACFFD458)                          = 0
 /17:    time()                                          = 1398686601
 /15:    ioctl(8, TCGETA, 0xACFFD53C)                    Err#25 ENOTTY
 /18:        Incurred fault #6, FLTBOUNDS  %pc = 0xFE27E498
 /18:          siginfo: SIGSEGV SEGV_MAPERR addr=0x8682F278
 /15:    write(8, " 1 3 : 0 3 : 2 1   -   1".., 43)      = 43
 /18:        Received signal #11, SIGSEGV [caught]
 /18:          siginfo: SIGSEGV SEGV_MAPERR addr=0x8682F278
 /15:    lseek(8, 0, SEEK_END)                           = 5887590
 /17:    open("Trade.log", O_RDWR|O_APPEND|O_CREAT, 0666) = 9
 /15:    llseek(8, 0, SEEK_CUR)                          = 5887590
 /17:    fstat64(9, 0xAB7FD4B0)                          = 0
 /15:    llseek(8, 0, SEEK_CUR)                          = 5887590
```

does i need to synchronized C code? or doing Thread with C?

i have try to use (*env)->MonitorEnter and (*env)->MonitorExit but same problem.

if i launch same program with only one thread, i have no problem and no memory leak.

**here is the C Code:**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "CTrade.h" 
 #include "../trace.h" 
 #include "../commun.h" 


  JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL      Java_fr_edf_mpv2_serveurcalcul_castor_transverse_traitement_transformation_courbe_TrtNRC_trade_1OM
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jfloatArray pmtPar, jobjectArray abqPar, jobjectArray donPar, jfloatArray    condPar, jobjectArray resPar, jintArray flagPar)
{
        float ** don0 = NULL ; // Pour pouvoir desallouer les elements Java
        float ** abq0 = NULL ; // Pour pouvoir desallouer les elements Java
 int err = 0 ;
 jfloat *pmt;// [SIZE_PMT] ; //parametres
 jfloat * abq ;//[SIZE_ABQ_2][SIZE_ABQ_1] ;  // abaques
 jfloat *cond;//[SIZE_COND] ; //Conditions
 jfloat * don ;//[SIZE_DON_2][SIZE_DON_1] ;  // Donnees
 jfloat * res ;//[SIZE_RES_2][SIZE_RES_1] ;  // Resultats
 int *flag ; //[SIZE_FLAG]  ;            // Retour Erreur
 int iFlag=0 ;
 SetLogFileName("Trade.log") ;
 ZTrace(" On est dans Trade.c");
 //
 // Init parametre : pmt
 //


 if((err = GetTableauFloat("pmt", env, pmtPar, & pmt))== 0)
 {
     //
     // Init parametre : abq
     //
     if((err = GetMatriceFloat("abq", env, abqPar,  & abq0, & abq)) == 0)
     {
         //
         // Init parametre : cond
         //
         if((err = GetTableauFloat("cond", env, condPar, & cond)) == 0)
         {
             //
             // Init parametre : don
             //
             if((err = GetMatriceFloat("don", env, donPar, & don0, & don)) == 0)
             {
                 //
                 // Allocation du tableau resultat
                 //
                 ZTrace("Allocation res") ;
                 if((err = AllocationMatriceFloat("res", env, resPar, & res)) == 0)
                 {
                     //
                     // Allocation du tableau flag
                     //
                     if((err = AllocationTableauInt("flag", env, flagPar, & flag)) == 0)
                     {
                        //here i have a Fortran Call that i remove because problem exist without this call          
                         if((err = TransfertTableauInt("flag", env, flagPar, flag)) == 0)
                         {
                                                                                               if((err = TransfertMatriceFloat("res", env, resPar, res)) == 0)
                             {
                             }
                         }
                         ZTrace("Libere Flag") ;
                         free(flag) ;
                     }
                     ZTrace("Libere res") ;
                     free(res) ;
                 }
                 ZTrace("Libere don");
                 free(don) ;
                 if(don0)
                     FreeMatriceFloat(env, donPar, don0) ;
             }
             (*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env, condPar, cond, JNI_ABORT) ;
         }
         ZTrace("Libere abq");
         free(abq);
         if(abq0)
             FreeMatriceFloat(env, abqPar, abq0) ;
     }
    (*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env, pmtPar, pmt, JNI_ABORT) ;
 }


return err;
 }
```

Trace.c only containt method for create file and write in it

**commun.c contains method to allocate array**

```
 int GetMatriceFloat(LPCSTR nomTab, JNIEnv *env, jobjectArray donPar, float * ** don, float ** donFor)
 {
int ind, jnd, sizeDon, sizeDon1 ;

 sizeDon = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, donPar);
 ZTrace("Size %s = %d", nomTab, sizeDon) ;
 if((* don = (jfloat **)calloc(sizeDon, sizeof(jfloat *))))
 {
     //
     // Init matrice don
     //
     for(ind = 0 ; ind < sizeDon ; ind ++)
     {
         jfloatArray donPari = (jfloatArray) (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, donPar, ind);
         sizeDon1 = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, donPari);
         ZTrace("Size1 %s = %d", nomTab, sizeDon1) ;
         (* don)[ind] = (jfloat *) (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env, donPari, NULL);
         if((* don)[ind] == NULL)
         {
             ZTrace("Erreur -23") ;
             return -23;/* exception occurred */
         }
     }

     if((* donFor = calloc(sizeDon1 * sizeDon, sizeof(float))) == NULL)
     {
         ZTrace("Erreur -22") ;
         return -22 ;
     }
     for(ind = 0 ; ind < sizeDon ; ind ++)
     {
         for(jnd = 0 ; jnd < sizeDon1 ; jnd ++)
         {
             * (* donFor + jnd * sizeDon + ind) = (* don)[ind][jnd] ;
             if((* don)[ind][jnd] != 0.0)
                 ZTrace("%s[%d][%d] = %g", nomTab, jnd, ind, (* don)[ind][jnd]) ;
         }
     }
     //free(don) ;
     return 0 ;
 }
 else
 {
    ZTrace("Erreur -24") ;
  return -24 ;
 }
 }

 int FreeMatriceFloat(JNIEnv *env, jobjectArray donPar, float ** don)
 {
 int ind, sizeDon ;
 sizeDon = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, donPar);
 for(ind = 0 ; ind < sizeDon ; ind ++)
 {
     jfloatArray donPari = (jfloatArray) (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, donPar, ind);
     (*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env, donPari, don[ind], JNI_ABORT);

 }
 free(don) ;
 }
```

if you see something in the call of getmatricefloat or something else let me know ;) if not i can post the others functions TransfertMatriceFloat/AllocationMatriceFloat/TransfertMatriceInt etc... to see if problem is in them

thanks by advance

Comment: How about posting the C-Code which is actually segfaulting? This does not appear to be a Java-problem, since the JVM does only segfault in extremely rare cases.

Comment: in fact, my question is : does it possible to have java multithread program that call C code (not multithreaded) without segfault? or i need to use pthread lib in C to create thread in C when java invoke C code? so i have a java thread and a C thread for each call? sorry if i m not clear...

Answer (score 0):

Calling any code that is not thread-safe has the potential to cause unforeseen problems.
Your symptom and bypass-fix scream loudly of the fact that your native code is not
thread-safe.

In your case, since you know with certainty that the 100ms delay prevents the
OS from seeing segmentation violations,  at a minimum, you should

```
remove the delay
```

and change

```
private native int myMethod(float[][] test, float[] tutu);
```

to

```
synchronized private native int myMethod(float[][] test, float[] tutu);
```

to prevent concurrent execution of you native code.

Comment: yes but synchronize work only if the same thread call the same method twice. But in my case native method is declared in myObject, and we are doing new MyObject each time. so synchronized will not work? solution to be synchronized work is to externalize in a singleton call of native method and doing them synchronized i think, i have post some informations in my initial ask( C code, truss log etc...)

Comment: @MançauxPierre-Alexandre - Not true - Once a thread enters a sync block/method and holds the monitor, that same thread can reenter the sync block/method (think about the use of method recursion). It is other threads (that do not hold the monitor) that are blocked.